# Reach blend shapes of ModelEntity in RealityView

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit, visionos

I load a usdz file in RealityView but I can not figure out how to reach blend shapes of a ModelEntity.
If I import the given file to the Blender I can see that the blend shapes are there.
Has someone got experience with that?